# Trying to convert python nested for loops to list/dict comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to turn the following code into something more readable.

```
for x in list_of_dicts:
    for y in header:
        if y not in x.keys():
            x[y] = ''
```

It takes a list of dictionaries and adds key:value pairs with the default value = '' for any
keys that do not already exist in the current dictionary.

I'm still new to python, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  I tried:

```
return [x[y] = '' for x in list_of_dicts for y in header if y not in x.keys()]
```

But I'm thinking you can't have "="

Comment: A comprehension is for building up a list, not for executing a sequence of assignment statements.

Comment: Perhaps look at making `list_of_dicts` into a list of `defaultdict` instead, so that you don't have to populate it explicitly for undefined keys?

Comment: `if y not in x.keys()` - drop the `keys()` call. On Python 2, that'll build an unnecessary list of keys and then iterate over them to find `y`, completely abandoning the benefits of using a dict. On Python 3, it's just unnecessary typing. `if y not in x` is what you want.

Comment: Also, dicts have a `setdefault` method that will set a default value for a key if the key is not already present, so if you want, you could use `x.setdefault(y, '')` and drop the `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem you should solve with a list comprehension. You *can* improve on your existing code using some set operations:

```
for x in list_of_dicts:
    x.update((y, '') for y in header.viewkeys() - x)
```

This'll achieve the same effect; add keys from `header` that are missing, as empty strings. For Python 3, replace `viewkeys()` with `keys()`.

This makes use of [dictionary view objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) to give us a set-like views on the dictionary keys; in Python 3 this behaviour is now the default.

If I read your question wrong and `headers` is not a dictionary as well, make it an explicit set to get the same benefits:

```
header_set = set(header)
for x in list_of_dicts:
    x.update((y, '') for y in header_set.difference(x))
```

Using set operations makes the code more readable and efficient, pushing any loops to determine the set difference into optimized C routines.

Comment: `header` may not actually be a dict.

Comment: @user2357112: indeed; I may have misread the question; I inferred and probably inferred wrong.

Comment: Presumably it's quite complex whether the additional work of creating a set for each `x` actually makes the set difference more or less efficient than the `not in` test. Probably depends on the size of it? Or is doing the iteration over `header` in Python so woefully slow compared with doing it in C that no amount of memory allocation will be slower?

Comment: The set setup is a one-time cost, easily won back in a few iterations over `list_of_dicts`. I am not in a position to run `timeit` trials right now, however. Yes, the C loop building the difference will outpace a byte-code driven loop by a good factor.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I mean the set constructed by `set.difference()`, to which there are `len(list_of_dicts)` calls not just one.

Comment: I see what you mean; I do think that it'll outpace even modest lengths of `header`, but would love to see time trials. Perhaps I'm way off!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that header was a list of strings :/

Comment: @MartijnPieters are you saying that the second for loop you wrote would run faster than `[dict(x, **{y: '' for y in header if y not in x}) for x in list_of_dicts]` that @jwodder wrote?

Comment: @MartijnPieters and @SteveJessop I most definitely should have explained this earlier, and I apologize.  `header` is a list of strings and for my purpose it will never be longer than 8 items; it's the column headers in a csv file.

Comment: @TroyKent: In practice you shouldn't worry about performance anyway, at least not unless you've written a first version and it seems slow. We've just jumped ahead to the step where if the first thing we try is slow, what might speed it up :-)

Comment: @TroyKent: I haven't had time to run any time trials for this, but I'd certainly expect in-place operations on existing dictionaries to be faster than building a completely new list object with new dictionaries, where the number of dictionaries doesn't differ between the two approaches. Do you absolutely need to create a new list with new dictionaries?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not at all, as long as I can return a list of dictionaries with the keys as strings from `header` instead of what they originally were.  I'm expecting to have all the keys currently in the `list_of_dicts` _and_ 2 or 3 more in `header`  For example, the dictionaries before look something like: `{'FIRST':'Troy', 'LAST':'Kent'}`  `header` would be something like `['FIRST', 'LAST', 'EMPLID', 'DOB']` and then the new dictionaries in the new list of dictionaries would look like: `{'FIRST':'Troy', 'LAST':'KENT', 'EMPLID':'','DOB':''}`

Answer (score 2):

You can't use dict comprehension to add items to a dict; dict comprehension creates a new dict separate from pre-existing ones, and if you want to combine the new and the old, you have to do so explicitly, such as:

```
for x in list_of_dicts:
    x.update({y: '' for y in header if y not in x})
```

(Note that `y not in x.keys()` is unnecessary when dealing with dicts, since you can just do `y not in x`.)

If you're dead-set on getting rid of that outer `for`, the way to do it is to create a new list of new dicts:

```
list_of_dicts2 = [dict(x, **{y: '' for y in header if y not in x}) for x in list_of_dicts]
```

Comment: Nice use of the `dict()` keyword arguments there to 'update' a new dictionary in the list comprehension!

Comment: If the keys aren't all strings, the second example won't work in Python 3.

Comment: @jwodder see above appreciation^

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use a list comprehension for this, but you shouldn't:

```
[x.setdefault(y, '') for x in list_of_dicts for y in header]
```

The reason you shouldn't is that this creates a big old list that you don't need but that takes time and memory.

You can consume a generator comprehension without creating a big old list:

```
import collections
def consume(iterator):
    collections.deque(iterator, maxlen = 0)

consume(x.setdefault(y, '') for x in list_of_dicts for y in header)
```

Arguably you shouldn't do this either, since readers don't really *expect* comprehensions to have side-effects so the code might frighten and confuse them.

You are correct that you can't do `x[y] = ''` in a comprehension, since it is a statement not an expression. It just so happens that `x.setdefault(y, '')` does what you want, but if there was no such convenient function then you could write one. And come to think of it, by doing that you can eliminate the comprehension as well as your original loop:

```
def set_default(x, y):
    if y not in x:
        x[y] = ''

consume(itertools.starmap(set_default, itertools.product(list_of_dicts, header))
```

Again though, some kind of warning about using generators for their side-effects should probably apply.

Comment: It's not a big list of `None`s, since `setdefault` returns the value of the key, but it is a big unnecessary list.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do this better. Primary by thinking better of what you are trying to do.

And what you are trying to do? You can think of it this way: you want to add defaults to some dicts. `dict.setdefault()` method immediately comes to mind:

```
for d in list_of_dicts:
    for h in header:
        d.setdefault(h, '')
```

You can think slightly other way: there are a set of defaults I need to apply to all of dicts. Now constructing `defaults` dict first and then merging it feels natural:

```
defaults = dict.fromkeys(header, '')
list_of_dicts = [dict(defaults, **d) for d in list_of_dicts]
```

Note that we are reconstructing each dict here not updating it. This is the right way when using comprehensions. One thing to add here is that merging last line with the code constructing `list_of_dicts` will probably make sense (I can't say for sure without seeing).

Comment: The list comprehension does assume that all keys in `d` are strings, but the `defaults` setup is a nice approach!

Comment: No it's not. Try this `dict({}, **{None: 1})` in python console.

Comment: Now try that in Python 3 :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d1={'a':1}
>>> d2={'b':2}
>>> d3={'c':3}
>>> listofdict=[d1, d2, d3]
>>> listofdict
[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]
>>> header = ['x', 'y']
>>> header
['x', 'y']
>>> [ x.update({k:''}) for x in listofdict for k in header if not x.get(k) ]
[None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> listofdict
[{'a': 1, 'x': '', 'y': ''}, {'y': '', 'x': '', 'b': 2}, {'y': '', 'x': '', 'c': 3}]
>>> d1
{'a': 1, 'x': '', 'y': ''}
>>> d2
{'y': '', 'x': '', 'b': 2}
>>> d3
{'y': '', 'x': '', 'c': 3}
>>>
```